# Broadcast message to actors watching a particular actor?

Tags: scala, akka, akka-remote-actor, akka-remoting

How can I broadcast a message to all actors that are watching a particular actor?

For context, suppose I have a `AuctionActor` (which is potentially a remote actor) that is being watched by a large number of `AuctionParticipantActor` types.  I would like the `AuctionActor` to broadcast various messages to `AuctionParicipantActor` types.

One possibility would be for the `AuctionActor` to keep a collection of all participant `ActorRef` instances and then loop over this collection when ever a message needs to be sent to all participants.  This seems inefficient and I am hoping for a better solution...

Comment: Distributed PubSub with the topic being the name of the actor seems a better solution than watching here

Comment: Do your `AuctionParticipantActor`s watch only one `AuctionActor` or multiple?

Comment: @thwiegan In general, each `AuctionParticipantActor` would want to monitor multiple `AuctionActor` instances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to go with [PubSub](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/distributed-pub-sub.html#distributedpubsub-extension) as mentioned by Diego Martinoia, I would suggest using `Routers` with `BroadcastingLogic`. This goes in the direction you mentioned with the collection of ActorRefs, but uses Akka functionality to achieve it being more efficient than just iterating over a collection in your `AuctionActor`.

From Akka [Docs](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#how-routing-is-designed-within-akka)

> Routers are designed to be extremely efficient at receiving messages and passing them quickly on to routees.
>
> A normal actor can be used for routing messages, but an actor’s single-threaded processing can become a bottleneck. Routers can achieve much higher throughput with an optimization to the usual message-processing pipeline that allows concurrent routing.

In your case it could look like this:

```
class AuctionActor extends Actor {
  var router = Router(BroadcastRoutingLogic(), Vector[ActorRefRoutee]())

  def receive = {
    case AddParticipant(ref) =>
      router = router.addRoutee(ref)
    case RemoveParticipant(ref) =>
      router = router.removeRoutee(ref)
    case update: ImportantUpdate =>
      router.route(update, self)
  }
}
```

Comment: Does it matter if the `ActorRef` is to a local actor or a remote actor? I think not...

Comment: That's a good question. I would expect it to be location transparent, but I think it shouldn't be hard to test. You can give it a try, I will do so as well, if I get to it. Would be great if you can give an update. Here seems to be info to remote routers: http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/current/scala/routing.html#remote-deployed-routees But that looks like it is used to create the routees on remote systems, where as in your case the routees already exist.

Comment: @davidrpugh Tested it, works with remote routees without changes to the code.